# Trying to create a webpage to remote detonate a model rocket

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, gpio

We are working on a Raspberry Pi project that works to remote launch a model rocket. The detonator is a website that displays a large, read "launch" button, which will prompt the raspberry pi to run a Python script that controls a GPIO pin that is connected to a relay board. The issue that I am having is when input the HTML code, the page turns up blank.

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I have Apache downloaded to host the website - have placed the html file in the /var/www/html folder and have also attempted to overwrite the code within the index.html file that was already in the folder. Additionally, I have placed the html file in my "rocket" folder which houses the Python script. None of these options have worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Launch Rocket</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         webiopi().ready(function() {                     
                 var button = webiopi().createGPIOButton(17, "Launch");                                 
                 $("#controls").append(button);                                 
                 webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);
         });
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
         button {
         display: block;
         margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
         width: 1280px;
         height: 720px;
         font-size: 100pt;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: white;
         }
         #gpio17.LOW {
         background-color: Red;
         }
         #gpio17.HIGH {
         background-color: Black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="controls" align="center"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

all attempts have resulted in a blank page.

Comment: "Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?"  Yeah!  You're allowing remote control of something dangerous without any local interlocks.  I hope you at least have a local key which physically disconnects the igniter from the power source, regardless of what the remote control says.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: @scritonboy - can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You are [following this part](https://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Basis.html#testing) Right? When you open the browser, right-click and click inspect element. Go to the console tab and see for any red icons or words. Those are possible errors in your code

Comment: I built something simular but used a arduino and controlled it remotely using bluetooth through a touch pad. Why use a HTML page? seems like its the wrong approach.

Comment: @weegee Thank you so much for the tutorial. I realized I was missing some of the configuration steps. I was able to get it to work!

Comment: Post an answer to this question (containing what was wrong in the answer) so it is not left un-answered and users can refer to it in the future @Turk happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial provided by @weegee, I realized that my issue was that I had been missing some of the configuration setup.

Tutorial: https://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Basis.html#testing

I was missing the pathway to the HTML file in my /etc/webiopi/ config, and as a result the Pi was not responding the way it should.